# Mongodb: get count of multiple values in a field grouped by another field

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a collection as below

```
{"country":"US","city":"NY"}
{"country":"US","city":"AL"}
{"country":"US","city":"MA"}
{"country":"US","city":"NY"}
{"country":"US","city":"MA"}
{"country":"IN","city":"DL"}
{"country":"IN","city":"KA"}
{"country":"IN","city":"DL"}
{"country":"IN","city":"DL"}
{"country":"IN","city":"KA"}
```

and expecting an output

```
{ "data": { "US": {"NY": 2,"AL": 1,"MA": 2 },
        "IN": {"DL": 3,"KA": 2 }}
}
```

Below is the mongodb query I tried, i was able to get to get the count at country level, but not at the state level.  please help me in correcting the below query to get data at state level.

```
db.country_dash.aggregate([
        {"$group": {
            "_id":"$country",
            "state": {"$addToSet": "$state"} 
        }},
        {"$project": {
            "_id":0,
            "country":"$_id",
            "state": {"$size": "$state"}
        } }
        ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.country_dash.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    city: '$city'
                },
                total: {
                    $sum: 1
                },
                country: {
                    $addToSet: '$country'
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $project: {
                total: 1,
                country: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ['$country', 0]
                },
                city: '$_id.city',
                _id: 0
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$country',
                data: {
                    $addToSet: {
                        city: '$city',
                        total: '$total'
                    }
                }
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: Below is the output on running against data,  {'_id': IN, 'data': [{'state': 'DL', 'total': 3},{'state': 'KA', 'total': 2}]}
{'_id': US, 'data': [{'state': 'NY', 'total': 2}, {'state': 'AL', 'total': 1}, {'state': 'MA', 'total': 2}]}     Got an idea to go about it, will tweak to fit my requirement, Thanks!